# How to convert numerical 'species' into categories in Iris dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, iris-dataset

I am working with the Iris dataset from `sklearn`. Here's my code so far:

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()

data = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'])
target = pd.DataFrame(iris['target'])

frames = [data,target]
iris = pd.concat(frames,axis=1)

iris.columns = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width','species']

def convert_target(data):
    if data == 0:
        return 'setosa'
    elif data == 1:
        return 'versicolor'
    else:
        return 'virginica'
iris['species'] = iris['species'].apply(convert_target)
```

Observe how I use `convert_target` function to convert the species from a numeric value to a categorical value. My question is, is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `map`:

```
d = {0: 'setosa', 1: 'versicolor', 2: 'virginica'}
iris['species'] = iris['species'].map(d)
```

You can also use numpy indexing:

```
cat_names = np.array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'])
iris['species'] = cat_names[iris['species']]
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `map` and `replace`? Is there any difference in terms of efficiency between the two?

Comment: `map` is generally faster, but turn the non-existing keys, e.g. `3,4` in this case, into `NaN`, while `replace` keeps them unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `map`, you can use `replace` using a dictionary:

```py
iris['species'] = iris['species'].replace({0:'setosa',1:'versicolor',2:'virginica'})
iris.samle(5)

     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width     species
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2      setosa
73            6.1          2.8           4.7          1.2  versicolor
138           6.0          3.0           4.8          1.8   virginica
6             4.6          3.4           1.4          0.3      setosa
140           6.7          3.1           5.6          2.4   virginica
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is a combination of all these answers. Create a dictionary from the target names. i used two variables. First i created a temp1 to create a list then i made a dictionary based on the location of the name in the list using temp2. Now the data frame column res["Y"] is replaced using the dictionary created. This is a more generic method for all scikit datasets

```
temp1 = iris_ds.target_names
temp2 = dict(enumerate(temp1))
res["Y"] = res["Y"].replace(temp2)
```

Since the full codes was asked

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_bunch = load_iris()
X, Y = iris_bunch.data, iris_bunch.target
iris_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.c_[data_iris,target_iris] ,
    columns = iris_ds['feature_names'] + ['target_names']
)
temp1 = iris_ds.target_names
temp2 = dict(enumerate(temp1))
res["Y"] = res["Y"].replace(temp2)
```

Now the data frame columns will have the target names instead of numeric values. This means we dont have to manually check and replace the values but its done as given in the dataset

---

final edit with working code

---

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
iris_bunch = load_iris()
data_iris, target_iris = iris_bunch.data, iris_bunch.target
iris_pd = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.c_[data_iris,target_iris] ,
    columns = iris_bunch['feature_names'] + ['target_names'])
print ("the target ouput is numeric",iris_pd.head(3))

temp1 = iris_bunch.target_names
temp2 = dict(enumerate(temp1))
iris_pd["target_names"] = iris_pd["target_names"].replace(temp2)
print ("the target ouput is target names",iris_pd.head(3))
```

Comment: Since you are not showing where `target_names` comes from, it's currently not clear from your code if it's going to create the exact same mapping that you see in the other answers, i.e. if 0 will map to `setosa`, 1 to `versicolor`, etc. You could improve your answer by including a *reproducible* example.

Comment: The scikit learn iris dataset is  a bunch and we get the target names from the bunch using this command. I assumed all are using the same dataset

Comment: Thanks for addressing my comment. Your variable names need to be aligned still for someone to be able to run your code.

Comment: yes they are alligned as per the original values of the target column. The target names are  given in dataset so tis code reedues the error of manual assignment. This is a very small set but when there are more ten names i would just code instead of hardcoding it

Comment: The point is that the code you posted does not run.

Comment: sorry i was working on another code. so just cut and pasted the code earlier without checking